# Copy from S3 to GCS files with different date

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow, google-cloud-storage

I have to move files from S3 to GCS. The problem i have is on mondays they uploads files from monday but also of saturdays and sundays and this files have different dates. For example: stack_20220430.csv, stack_20220501.csv. I need to move this files in the same airflow run, is that posible?  I'm using the S3ToGCSOperator:

```
S3ToGCSOperator(
        task_id="move_files_s3_to_gcs",
        bucket=config["s3_params"]["s3_source_bucket"],
        prefix=config["s3_params"]["s3_source_prefix"],
        delimiter="/",
        dest_gcs=config["gcs_params"]["gcs_destination"],
        aws_conn_id=config["s3_params"]["s3_connector_name"],
    )
```

Obviously the problem is that prefix takes a fixed value. I can assign a range for {{ds}}?

Answer (score 1):

The `S3ToGCSOperator` copy/move all files in the bucket/key you provided. It does it by [listing](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0fcdc5e1fb4f49bc9c35eec99a6c3ea65f704588/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/s3_to_gcs.py#L144-L145) all of them and then [iterate each file](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0fcdc5e1fb4f49bc9c35eec99a6c3ea65f704588/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/s3_to_gcs.py#L183) and copy it to GCS.

[`prefix`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0fcdc5e1fb4f49bc9c35eec99a6c3ea65f704588/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/s3_to_gcs.py#L98) is templated field so you can use `{{ ds }}` with it.

You can always inherit from `S3ToGCSOperator` and customize the behavior of the operator to your specific needs.